Lubuntu Security
I’m currently working on securing my Lubuntu system and have already implemented several basic security measures like configuring a firewall, managing user permissions, and setting up SSH. However, I’m wondering if there are any additional steps I can take to further enhance the security of my system.
For context, I’m looking for recommendations on:
Tools or commands for monitoring system activity and logs.
Methods to secure sensitive files or user data.
Suggestions for preventing unauthorized access, beyond SSH configuration.
Any other lesser-known but useful security practices specifically for Lubuntu.

I’d appreciate any tips or advice from the community. Thank you in advance!
